# How to make a copy constructor for different types within a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++14, const-iterator

I need to make my `Iterator< isConst = false>` convert to `Iterator<isConst = true>`. That is, I need a separate method `Iterator< true >(const Iterator< false > &)`.

My Iterator class:

```
template < typename T >
template < bool isConst >
class ForwardList< T >::Iterator
{
  using value_type = std::conditional_t< isConst, const T, T >;
  using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
  using pointer = std::conditional_t< isConst, const T *, T * >;
  using reference = std::conditional_t< isConst, const T &, T & >;
  using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

  friend class ForwardList< T >;
private:
  explicit Iterator(node_t *nodePtr): nodePtr_(nodePtr) {}
public:
  Iterator() = default;
  Iterator(const Iterator &other) = default;
  ~Iterator() = default;

  reference operator*() const;
  pointer operator->() const;
  Iterator &operator++();
  Iterator operator++(int) &;
  bool operator==(const Iterator &other) const;
  bool operator!=(const Iterator &other) const;

private:
  node_t *nodePtr_;
};
```

I tried overloading the copy constructor and specializing the template. I understand that if you split the Iterator into two classes, it can be done, but I don't want to duplicate so much code.

Comment: Aside: if a constructor takes a parameter of some other type, it isn't a copy constructor (even if that other type is a instantiation of the same template)

Comment: Have a look at `std::vector` implementation. I think this is usually implemented as `ForwardListIterator` inheriting `ConstForwardListIterator`.

Comment: Warning: Rule of 3 violation here. You should create the assignment operators corresponding to the "copy constructor"s. Also I strongly recommend initializing the `nodePtr_` with `nullptr` in the default constructor, since this will more reliably crash the code on invalid use. As for implementing this: Just implement a templated constructor and use `std::enable_if` or concepts to disable the constructor that would allow you to construct a non-const iterator from a const iterator.

Comment: The type aliases should be public btw. Furthermore I recommend using `value_type` to avoid repeated `std::conditional_t` uses: `using pointer = value_type*; using reference = value_type&;`

Comment: @rturrado I tried this, but I don't understand how then I can override `operator*` and `operator->` if they will return values of a different type (T instead of const T)?

Comment: @fromgate My understanding is that those methods are not virtual/overriden, just hidden/redefined in the subclass.

Comment: @fabian Thanks, but I don't understand what method is called when `Iterator< isConst = false >` is implicitly converted to `Iterator< isConst = true >`? And how do I implement `Iterator< true >(const Iterator< false > &)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than having a constructor that takes an `Iterator<false>`, you can have a conversion operator that returns an `Iterator<true>`.

```
operator Iterator<true>() const { return Iterator<true>(nodePtr_); }
```

You will need to `friend class Iterator<false>;` to access your private constructor.

[See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90460094b0266ab6)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the iterator constructor that accepts iterators with arbitrary template parameters, unless the constructed iterator is a non-const iterator and the constructor parameter is a const iterator:

```
template < typename T >
template < bool isConst >
class ForwardList< T >::Iterator
{
...

    friend class ForwardList<T>::Iterator<!isConst>;
public:
    Iterator() = default;

    template<bool otherIsConst, std::enable_if_t<isConst || !otherIsConst, int> = 0>
    Iterator(Iterator<otherIsConst> const& other)
        : nodePtr_(other.nodePtr_)
    {
    }

    ~Iterator() = default;
    ...
private:
    node_t* nodePtr_ {nullptr}; // note: crash more likely for dereferencing the default-constructed object
};

static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ForwardList<int>::Iterator<true>, ForwardList<int>::Iterator<true> const&>, "expected constructor unavailable");
static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ForwardList<int>::Iterator<true>, ForwardList<int>::Iterator<false> const&>, "expected constructor unavailable");
static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ForwardList<int>::Iterator<false>, ForwardList<int>::Iterator<false>const&>, "expected constructor unavailable");
static_assert(!std::is_constructible_v<ForwardList<int>::Iterator<false>, ForwardList<int>::Iterator<true> const&>, "unexpected constructor available");
```